# How to reuse data fetching logic from api using react custom hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two components rendering different UI based on user type. Both components have nearly 50% similar logic of fetching data from api, connecting to store.

I tried, reusing the login by creating custom hook.

```
const { products, loading} = useFetchProducts(userId);
```

and now I can define a useFetchProducts reducer

```
  const useFetchProducts= (userId) => {
   const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);
   const [ products, setProducts ] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
       setLoading(true);
         fetchUserProducts(userId).then((res) => {
           setLoading(false);
           setProducts(res.data);  
     }); 
   }, [])
 }
```

How do I return products and loading state to my component from this reducer to hide or show a loader as well as to show list of products,

Comment: you can pass the props in other component through import in parent class

Comment: My question here is this, how to get state of loader in the component where I a using this custom hook. How to pass state from custom hook to component?

Comment: you can import spinner component in parent class, then setState and pass the state value in spinner component as a props through custom hooks

Comment: useEffect(() => {
       setLoading(true);
         fetchUserProducts(userId).then((res) => {
           setLoading(false);
           setProducts(res.data);  
     }); 
   }, [])

render(){
return (
// pass here hooks state value
 <spinner value={hooks state value} />

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to return the values from the custom hook.

```
const useFetchProducts= (userId) => {
   const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);
   const [ products, setProducts ] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
       setLoading(true);
         fetchUserProducts(userId).then((res) => {
           setLoading(false);
           setProducts(res.data);  
     }); 
   }, [])
   return {loading, products}
 }
```

It will work because when the data is available it will cause a re-render and due to that, the component in which you use the custom hook will re-render causingthe update

Comment: yes thanks , this makes somesense now. I will try this out now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return value from your custom hook.

```
const useFetchProducts= (userId) => {
   const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);
   const [ products, setProducts ] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
       setLoading(true);
         fetchUserProducts(userId).then((res) => {
           setLoading(false);
           setProducts(res.data);  
     }); 
   }, [])
   return { products, loading }
 }
```

Comment: How can you be sure it will only return data once useEffect finishes its call.
I don't think this will work.this will only return { products: false, loading: false}

Comment: It will return updated data in each render. your useEffect will cause re-render when you set products and loading values. so in next render you will get updated loading and products.